# Does Google Analytics have a way to compare two timeframes?

Tags: google-analytics

Our site recently took a huge traffic hit that we can't attribute to anything.  Is there a way to ask Google Analytics to compare traffic patterns and show any statistical changes between two timeframes? (Or 3rd party software)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Google](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57160)

> **How do I select and compare date ranges for my reports?**
>
> Google Analytics maintains at least 25
> months of historical data for each
> site tracked using Google Analytics.
> You can easily view reports for any
> date range for which data exists. The
> date range selector at the top right
> of your report pages allows you to
> select a date range, and optionally to
> compare that range to another date
> range of your choosing.
>
> Click the down arrow next to the date
> to access the date range selector.
> Once you've selected a new date range,
> click Apply Range to update your
> report.
>
> **To select a single date**
>
> - Click the **Calendar** tab and click any
>   date on the calendar.
> - From the
>   **Timeline** tab, you can also drag the
>   start or end slider to its smallest
>   setting.
> - Or, enter a single date in
>   mm/dd/yyyy format in both fields of
>   the **Date Range** section.
>
> **To select a
> specific week**
>
> - Click the **Calendar** tab and click the
>   icon to the left of any calendar week.
>
> **To select a range of dates**
>
> - From the **Calendar** tab, click once on
>   the desired start date, then click the
>   end date. The selected days will be
>   highlighted.
> - The **Timeline** tab lets you
>   drag the start and end date sliders to
>   any desired date. Your selection will
>   be displayed in the **Date Range** text
>   boxes to the right of the timeline.
> - You can also enter a start and end
>   date in the **Date Range** fields, using
>   mm/dd/yyyy format.
>
> **To compare two different ranges**
>
> Select the **Compare to Past** checkbox
> and follow the instructions above to
> select a date range. **Change** values in
> your reports will be calculated
> against the selected **Compare to Past**
> range.
>
> Remember: once you've selected a new
> date range, click **Apply Range** to
> update your report